# how to echo a javascript script with php through ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I want a javascript script to be echoed when a condition is true,
the file where this script is on is called through ajax by another page
and for some reason it wont echo the `<script>...</script>` part.
If i put a regular string there it works but it just wont echo javascript.

```
$max = $int + 10;
  if($max >= $num_rows){
    $end = "<script>var end=1</script>";
  } else {
    $end = "<script>var end=0</script>";
  }

 echo $end;
```

ajax:
    function onScroll(event) {
              // Check if we're within 100 pixels of the bottom edge of the broser window.
              var closeToBottom = ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100);

```
          if(closeToBottom) {

            if(end==0){
             // GET THE 10 NEXT ITEMS;
              if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                 {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                 }
               else
                 {// code for IE6, IE5
                 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                 }
               xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                 {
                 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                   {
                   //document.getElementById("tiles").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;




                         $('#tiles').append(innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText);
                         int = int+10;
                         // Clear our previous layout handler.
                         if(handler) handler.wookmarkClear();

                         // Create a new layout handler.
                         handler = $('#tiles li');
                         handler.wookmark(options);


                         $(function() {
                            // Select all links whose attribute rel starts with lightbox
                            $('a[rel^=lightbox]').lightBox();
                         });


                           FB.XFBML.parse();

                   }

                 }
            } 
               $.extend({
                    getUrlVars: function(){
                      var vars = [], hash;
                      var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
                      for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
                      {
                        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
                        vars.push(hash[0]);
                        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
                      }
                      return vars;
                    },
                    getUrlVar: function(name){
                      return $.getUrlVars()[name];
                    }
                  });

                  var request = $.getUrlVar('item');

                  if(request!=null){
                    var allR = "?int="+int+"&item="+request;
                  } else {
                    var allR = "?int="+int;
                  }


               xmlhttp.open("GET","tiles.php"+allR,true);
               xmlhttp.send();


             }

        };
```

Can anyone solve this?
Thx in advance.

Comment: You should also show the Ajax part. Php looks fine.

Comment: I dont think the Ajax part is the problem beceaus everything else i am sending over ajax loads, it's only the javascript part that doesnt show. But here is it anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is you have to go through the DOM tree of the document bit you download through Ajax and manually evaluate it using `eval`, because for security reasons browsers do not automatically parse and run the JavaScript code embedded through remote calls for you.

You can do something like this:

```
var scripts = domElement.getElementsByTagName("script");
for (var i = 0; i < scripts; i ++) {
    eval(scripts[i].text);
}
```

Comment: It works now but i parse facebook xml afterwards and that doesnt anymore now and if i put the facebook parse xml first the rest of the code doesnt work anymore...

Comment: How do you mean _following_? Do you mean that after the code I wrote executes, no more JavaScript runs on the page?

Comment: `$(function() {
                              // Select all links whose attribute rel starts with lightbox
                              $('a[rel^=lightbox]').lightBox();
                             });
                             
                             var scripts = domElement.getElementsByTagName("script");
                               for (var i = 0; i < scripts; i ++) {
                                   eval(scripts[i].text);
                               }
                               
                               FB.XFBML.parse();`

Comment: This means that a JS error occurs during the execution of `FB.XFBML.parse()` and that in turn stops the execution of the code. So, your current problem (that of scripts retrieved through Ajax not executing) is solved, and you must now correct the other errors.

Comment: You are welcome. I suggest you post this problem if it gets too hairy for you and explain it sufficiently, and then you can get out of the way as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the eval() in the javascript to load the javascript. Just checkout the below example

```
   var div = document.getElementById("tiles");
   div.innerHTML =xmlhttp.responseText;
   var x = div.getElementsByTagName("script"); 
   for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
   {
       eval(x[i].text);
   }
```

This is a small fragment code you should inject in the place where you have received the response. Hope this helps.